# Why does elevation shadow vary between two different views in Android Studio?

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout

I have a LinearLayout which inside of it contains alot of RelativeLayouts as you can see in the simple demonstration I provide.

But for some reason, the second MAIN TAB 2 (android:id="@+id/ResultInformation" in the real code) shows a way stronger elevation shadow than the MAIN TAB 1 (android:id="@+id/ProfileInformation" in the real code).

I don't get why this is happening??? Help.

### Simple Demonstration (Not correct syntax, I know)

```
<LinearLayout orientation = vertical>

    <RelativeLayout> MAIN TAB 1 </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout> ITEM 1 </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout> ITEM 2 </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout> ITEM 3 </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout> MAIN TAB 2 </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout> ITEM 1 </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout> ITEM 2 </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout> ITEM 3 </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

### ACTUAL CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".profile_fragment"
    android:background="@color/darkerwhite"
    android:id="@+id/profile_frag">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/ProfileInformation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="21pt"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:background="@color/darkwhite">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:text="Profile"
                android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="19dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/HeightProfile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="26pt"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:elevation="1dp"

                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvHeight"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                    android:text="Height (cm)"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkestgrey"

                    />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etHeight"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:maxLength="3"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:hint="cm"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/textGray"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/WeightProfile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="26pt"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:elevation="1dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvWeight"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                    android:text="Weight (kg)"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkestgrey"

                    />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etWeight"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:maxLength="3"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:hint="kg"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/textGray"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/AgeProfile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="26pt"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:elevation="1dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvAge"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                    android:text="Age"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkestgrey"

                    />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etAge"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:maxLength="3"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:hint="years"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/textGray"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/GenderProfile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="26pt"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:elevation="1dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvGender"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                    android:text="Gender"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkestgrey"

                    />


            </RelativeLayout>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvGenderSelector"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18dp"

                />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/ActivityProfile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="26pt"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:elevation="1dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvActivity"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                    android:text="Activity"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkestgrey"

                    />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvActivitySelector"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18dp">

            </TextView>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/GoalProfile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="26pt"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:elevation="1dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvGoal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                    android:text="Goal"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkestgrey"

                    />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvGoalSelector"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text=""
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18dp">

            </TextView>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/ResultInformation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="21pt"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:background="@color/darkwhite">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:text="Results"
                android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="19dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/BasalMetabolicRateProfile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="32pt"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:background="@color/white">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/tvBasalMetabolicRateClick"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:clickable="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/date_changer_forwards"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:elevation="1dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageBMR"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/fire_vector_yellow" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageBMR"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvBasalMetabolicRate"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                        android:text="Basal Metabolic Rate"
                        android:textColor="@color/black" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvBasalMetabolicRateCalculator"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/tvBasalMetabolicRate"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                        android:text="-"
                        android:textColor="@color/darkestgrey"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </RelativeLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/BodyMassIndexProfile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="32pt"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/tvBodyMassIndexClick"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:clickable="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/date_changer_forwards"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:elevation="1dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageBMI"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/person_vector_yellow" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageBMI">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvBodyMassIndex"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                        android:text="Body Mass Index"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvBodyMassIndexCalculator"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/tvBodyMassIndex"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:text="-"
                        android:textColor="@color/darkestgrey"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/waterRequirementProfile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="32pt"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/tvWaterRequirementClick"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:clickable="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/date_changer_forwards"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:elevation="1dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageWaterRequirement"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/water_vector_lightblue"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageWaterRequirement"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvWaterRequirement"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                        android:text="Water Requirement (ml)"
                        android:textColor="@color/black" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvWaterRequirementCalculator"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/tvWaterRequirement"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                        android:text="-"
                        android:textColor="@color/darkestgrey"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/dailyCaloricRequirementProfile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="32pt"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/tvDailyCaloricRequirementClick"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:clickable="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/date_changer_forwards"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:elevation="1dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageDCR"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/fire_vector_lightred" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageDCR"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvCaloricRequirement"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                        android:text="Daily Caloric Requirement"
                        android:textColor="@color/black" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvCaloricRequirementCalculator"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/tvCaloricRequirement"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                        android:text="-"
                        android:textColor="@color/darkestgrey"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It's unclear exactly how much stronger you're talking about here, but Android's native shadows will vary with their on-screen position, with shadows toward the bottom of the screen appearing slightly darker than those toward the top. This is due to the two-source rendering model used, and the spotlight that's "overhead" at the top of the screen. You might be able to notice the shadows shifting when scrolling one of those `View`s from top to bottom and back.

Comment: So there is no fix for this?

Comment: Well, if that is indeed the issue here, not really. Starting with API level 28, you could possibly disable the spotlight-generated shadows by setting the alpha to zero, causing everything to have only the shadows from the ambient source, but that's more of a hack, and is only available starting with Pie. Would you be able to post a screenshot, just to be sure that we're talking about the same thing?

Comment: I would also mention that if the backgrounds are translucent – i.e., if your `darkwhite` color has an alpha component < `FF` – then you're likely seeing a framework glitch that would cause the difference to be much more noticeable, which might be why the one appears way stronger in your setup.